# Fast shell command to remove stop words in a text file

Tags: shell, nlp, text-processing

I have a 2GB text file. I am trying to remove frequently occurring english stop words from this file.

I have stopwords.txt containing like this..

```
a
an
the
for
and
I
```

What is the fast method to do this using shell command such as tr, sed or awk?

Comment: Do you mean fastest to type, or fastest to execute?

Comment: Yes to execute on large data?

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea – why do you want to have a 2GB copy with unreadable text? If you're planning to do information retrieval you need to preprocess (tokenisation, stemming) and index the text anyway, so why not just skip the stopwords at a later stage?

Comment: Where did they say anything about information retrieval?

Comment: @Dan they didn't, I just think it's a likely scenario. But what I said also holds for any other NLP task requiring stopword removal that I can think of.

Comment: @Lenz I am not planning to do NLP tasks as i am training the entire dataset on word2vec. Just need to remove few common stopwords to see how the accuracy is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method using the command line and `perl`:

Save the text below as `replacesw.sh`:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
MYREGEX=\\b\(`perl -pe 's/\n/|/g' $1`\)\\b
perl -pe "s/$MYREGEX//g" $2
```

Then if you have saved your file above as `stopwords.txt`, and have a second file (e.g.) called `testtext.txt` that contains:

```
This is a file with the stopwords from the stopwords.txt for testing.
More than one line in the file, for a better test.
```

Then the following at the command line will remove the `stopwords`:

```sh
KBs-MBP13:temp kbenoit$ ./replacesw.sh stopwords.txt testtext.txt 
This is  file with  stopwords from  stopwords.txt  testing.
More than one line in  file,   better test.
```

You might need to `chmod u+x replacesw.sh` first.

Comment: You'll need perl installed, and the syntax will differ on a Windows platform.

Comment: FYI, i am using Mac OSX. Checking on perl installation :)

Comment: Error message please?

Comment: Perl is installed of course. No errors whatsoever, it outputs the contents of input file with no words replaced. :) `./replaceSW.sh stopwords.txt input.txt` and the output `how about i decide to look at it afterwards what
across do you think is it a good idea to go out and about i 
think id rather go up and above`. You can clearly see the stopwords `to,is,i...` not removed

Comment: Odd - I just reran it and it's definitely working for me.

Comment: I just tested again. it works fine in ubuntu but not in Mac OSX. Looks there is a problem with perl regular expression with osx

Comment: Works on my OS X:

 `KBsMBP15:~ kbenoit$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)'