# Omit words in a text

Tags: regex, bash, text-processing

Let's say I have this file (`file.txt`):

```
Hello my name is Giorgio,
I would like to go with you
to the cinema my friend
```

I want to exclude from the text the words: `my`, `is` and `I` (not the whole line).

The words are in a file (`words.txt`) like this:

```
my
is
I
```

So the output must be:

```
Hello name Giorgio,
would like to go with you
to the cinema friend
```

How can this be performed?

Comment: Is bash mandatory? This is the kind of tasks where Perl shines.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what did you try so far. this can be approached in many ways. The basic case is quite fast, only that it then needs to handle trailing spaces, etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574124/fast-shell-command-to-remove-stop-words-in-a-text-file/30670061#30670061 for a very similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sed to turn words.txt into a sed script:

```
sed 's=^=s/=;s=$=//g=' words.txt | sed -f- file.txt
```

The difference to the expected output is the whitespace: removing a word doesn't squeeze the surrounding whitespace.

To match only whole words, add the word boundaries `\b`:

```
s=^=s/\\b=;s=$=\\b//g=
```

Perl solution that also squeezes the spaces (and doesn't care about meta characters):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $WORDS, '<', 'words.txt' or die $!;
my %words;
chomp, $words{$_} = q() while <$WORDS>;

open my $TEXT, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
while (<$TEXT>) {
    s=( ?\b(\S+)\b ?)=$words{$2} // $1=ge;
    print;
}
```

Comment: I was just writing up a similar answer using a `while read` but this one is definitely better, having no temp files and all. On a side note, should there not be a space in between `-f` and `-`? Or is that not required

Comment: This will remove anything that contains the words and not just the whole words.

Comment: Yep this is probably the best answer now, although like mine it will still die if there are meta characters.

Comment: @User112638726: Define a "whole word containing meta characters".

Comment: @choroba Who said they were whole words, if you were referring to my previous comment, I'm simply pointing out caveats for edge cases.

Comment: Hello, it works pretty well, but not then the word is at the end of the word, even with  s=^=s/\\b=;s=$=\\b//g=

for example: My name is Camy ->  name is Ca

Anyways is a very good advance

Comment: @aDoN: Which of the three solutions do you mean? Do you want to remove whole words only, or just substrings?

Comment: @choroba Whole words only, I tried with the \\b but when at the end of the word, it doesn't work.

Any way I could contact you on private if you are not very busy¿? I have been using sed  for a long time and thought I knew how to use it but they way you use it puzzled me

Comment: @aDoN: The `\\b` solution doesn't remove `my` from `Camy` for me.

Comment: Yeah, do you have any idea how to carry that out ¿?  
And other question, I don't know what you did, could you someway explain it to me in private¿? Because I have a couple of question that would take up too much space, and since there are no private messages in stackoverflow , that's the only way I can contact you

Comment: @aDoN: Just remove the `| sed ...` to see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80911/discussion-between-adon-and-choroba).

Comment: @aDoN: Sorry, blocked from here :(

Comment: Finally based on your answer a post what I'm finally gonna implement, I post here in case some people like me are not familiar with your syntax.

Thank you very much, it was not an very easy problem:

`sed  -e 's/^/s\/\\b/g' -e 's/$/\\b\/\/g/g' words.txt | sed -f - file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp file.txt newfile.txt # we will change newfile.txt in place
while IFS= read -r line;do
[[ $line != "" ]] && sed -i "s/\b$line[[:space:]]*//g" newfile.txt
done <words.txt
cat newfile.txt
```

Or modifying @choroba's `sed` solution:

```
sed 's=^=s/\\b=;s=$=[[:space:]]*//g=' words.txt | sed -f- file.txt
```

Both of the above will strip spaces (if any) from the end of matching string.

Output:

```
Hello name Giorgio,
would like to go with you
to the cinema friend #There's a space here (after friend)
```

Comment: It doesn't remove `I` at the beginning of the 2nd line.

Comment: @choroba I have changed it again, and modified your method to strip spaces, It will leave space if the word is at the end of the line though.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty scruffy version in awk. If the list of words contains meta characters then this will die.It does take into account word boundaries though, so won't match in the middle of words.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}
     {for(i in a)gsub("(^|[^[:alpha:]])"i"([^[:alpha:]]|$)"," ")}1' {words,file}.txt

Hello name Giorgio,
 would like to go with you
to the cinema friend
```

It saves the words from the first file into array `a`. 
In the next file for each word saved it simply removes that word from the line using alpha(All alphabetic characters) and the line beginning and end to ensure the word is a complete word. `1` prints the line.

Comment: @fedorqui Edited, that was left over from another method i was going to use :D

Comment: ⁧‮  ‭hello over ⁧ there‭‮

Comment: ‭1⁪2⁪34⁨⁨⁪⁪sdds‮322345